# Database Performance Improvement Structural Design

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, entity-framework, database-design

I has a structural performance question.

I am preparing a book selling web site. I has books, authors, categories ect. I want to give users some discounts. But these discount can be about book, category, author and even can be about user. I am storing discounts at 'discounts' table and storing types. When people list products, i want to show discounts too. If i join discounts table and product table and check for total discount for each record that is a huge performance issue for listing. Do you have any suggestion for this and something like this situations?

(Note: I can put discount into product table and calculate it daily with a sql job but i has more tables with that problem. Discounts is just a sample and i wanna learn alternative ways for something like these issues.)

Sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i join discounts table and product table and check for total
>   discount for each record that is a huge performance issue for listing.

Ah. No. Tried 10 years ago for an online shop we created and we figured out that with some simple caching (shop products, with all elements together) in memory (we could live showing 5 minutes outdated prices in case of a change) plus output cache of the non-super-simple way we could mitigate pretty much all the performance impact.

Make a clear database. Then make a smart architecture on top of it. Not every item must all the time be queried from the database.

Comment: That can be a solution but is that enought? If you say i used it for large datas and has not much performance issue with that, i will do like you say.

Comment: Define large data. I have no problem putting in a 64gb web server for a larger shop and / or pushing that into a cascade of memory caching servers. Problem is: it is the only solution because you can either be flexible, or fast in this scenario, and only a cache can handle the combination of both. Throwing some memory at it is a valid solution in this case.